# Automatically republish old posts

Tags: posts, get-posts, date

been seaching on google for a plugin for this and can't seem to find anything realiable. The only plugin I found is called "old post promoter". Any ideeas?
Can this be done with googl old fashion coding, not a plugin?

Ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/oldest-2-newest-redux/

it takes your oldest post and reposts it in the front every 24 hours, but you can change the hours on the php file in the plugin folder

not sure if this is what u are looking for.

Comment: Seems very interesting, does it work with latest versions of wordpress and wordpress multisite?

Comment: @webmasters take a look at the link: last update, published, compatible versions - then test.

Comment: it does work on the lastest version, it is pretty simple code, as for multisite I am not sure but works for sure on latest